# Optional but conditional argument python

Tags: python, arguments

So let's say I have a function which takes two params, but at least one of them should be present:

```
 def foo_bar(foo = None, bar = None):
```

The problem is that both of them are optional, but in practice either `foo` or `bar` will be passed in.
Right now I check for existence in the function like this:

```
do_this() if foo else do_that() sort of logic..
```

But I don't like the way this looks.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Have you thought about using keyword args instead?

Comment: @JoelCornett: The OP is using keyword arguments already.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I meant `**kwargs`.

Comment: Would it be an error for both arguments to be `None`, or just unlikely?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Those appear to be positional args with default values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've got it right. The params can also be read with the `kwargs` syntax:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'foo' in args:
        do_this()
    elif 'bar' in args:
        do_that()
    else:
        raise ValueError()
```

OR, you could do something like this:

```
def foo(param, flag):
    if flag == 'foo':
        do_this()
    elif flag == 'bar':
        do_that()
    else:
        raise ValueError()
```

Either way should be fine. Hope this helps

Comment: not sure what's better about the **kwargs version compared to the original... I like the param/flag version though.

Comment: It works as flags like you said. It also works in allowing params to be passed in any (essentially orderless) order. The key/value pairs of the `dict` become how params are passed (and parsed), as opposed to the positional passing of parameters which is what would happen if the function signature was `def foo(param1, param2, …)`. Also, check out the answers to [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

Comment: I know how that works, but with a signature like `def foo(x,y,z)` you can *also* pass the parameters in any order by name (`foo(z=1, x=2, y=3)`), which is why I'm not sure there's any advantage to the `**kwargs` signature in this case.

Answer (score 2):

3 ways to deal with it come to mind:

If you can switch behavior based upon some rules about the parameters (one is of one type, one is of another, one matches 1 regex, 1 another, etc), pass one parameter and figure out what to do inside the function.

Create 2 functions that both call some other function for their shared behavior but handle the foo and bar specific cases independently.

Pass 1 data value and another control value:

```
def foo_bar(val, control):
    if control=='foo':
        #Do foo stuff
    elif control=='bar':
        #Do bar stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, but What if both are specified?  What I usually do is:

```
def some_func(foo=None, bar=None):
    "either one, or neither, but not both, are allowed"
    if foo is not None and bar is not None:
        raise TypeError("cannot specify both 'foo' and 'bar'")
    if foo is not None:
        pram = foo
    elif bar is not None:
        pram = bar
    else:
        pram = None  # or whatever
```

Simple, easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply check to see which one is None, and say that the other one must be the one that is present?

```
if foo == None:
    do bar()
elif bar == None:
    do foo()
else:
    throwUpYourHandsInFrustration()
```